# How can I setup proxy using Vercel

Tags: proxy, vercel

My API it's running under another domain.. and I'm trying to configure proxy with Vercel ..

The app it's making requests to `/api/test.json` so I tried to...  on vercel configuration

```
"redirects": [
        {
            "source": "/api/test.json",
            "destination": "https://myapi.com/test.json",
        }
    ],
    "rewrites": [
        {
            "source": "/(.*)",
            "destination": "/index.html"
        }
    ]
```

And I received 404 from `/api/test.json`

Comment: How did you solve your problem mate @ridermansb?

Answer (score 5):

Use the [wildcard path matching](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites#wildcard-path-matching) *`:path*`* syntax:

```
// in vercel.json:
// for example proxying /api/ → https://backend-endpoint/

{
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/api/:path*",
      "destination": "https://backend-endpoint/:path*"
    },
    {
      "source": "/api/:path*/",
      "destination": "https://backend-endpoint/:path*/"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

**NOTE:** **You need both very identical objects under `rewrites` array as above in order to make things work properly**. The example in the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites#wildcard-path-matching) is only the one without the trailing slash and it won't convert *(for example)* `/api/auth/login/` to `https://backend-endpoint/auth/login/`, that example can only convert `/api/auth/login` to `https://backend-endpoint/auth/login` (without trailing slash `/`)

*(it took me a day to realize that trailing slash `/` is actually very important)*.

Comment: Wow.  I had the same problem with the trailing slash and also spent an entire day on it until I saw this.  Thanks, Loi!

Answer (score 4):

Simply use rewrites

```
"rewrites": [
    {
        "source": "/api/test.json",
        "destination": "https://myapi.com/test.json",
    }
]
```

Then in your application

```
httpAgent
  .get('/api/test.json)
  .then(res => { console.log(res) })
```